# python virtualenv set up from mac - use it in linux

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, virtualenv

Is it possible to set up a virtualenv on a Dropbox folder from a Mac and activate that from Ubuntu that also has access to that Dropbox folder?
I seem to be able to call `source env/bin/activate` and it activates the environment, but when I call `which python`, it gives me `/usr/bin/python` instead of the one in the virtual environment

Before I do anymore troubleshooting/add more details, is this possible at all and am I just doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, because virtualenv use absolute paths to setup the environment.
Also it's kind of the reverse of what virtualenv is created for.

Comment: How so? There are obvious things which will not work (libraries compiled for a specific platform, for example) but if you can run `activate` successfully, the basic functionality should work.

Comment: A better approach is to make the virtualenv easy to reproduce; using [`pip install -r requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files) should be all it takes.